# exact closed form expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, closed-form

The question is to find the exact closed form of the expression

$(0^2+...+n^2)+(1^2+...+(n+1)^2)+...+(n^2+...+(2n)^2)$

Hint (find the exact closed form of $(n)(1^2)+(n-1)(2^2)+...+(1)(n^2)$ first).

The exact closed form of the hint
$=(n)(1^2)+(n-1)(2^2)+...+(1)(n^2)$ 
$=(n)(1+(2^2)+(3^2)+...+n^2)-(2^2+(2)(3^2)+...+(n-1)(n^2))$
$=n((1/3)(n^3)+(1/2)(n^2)+(1/6)(n))-...$(I do not know how to evaluate this term)

I also do not know about the relationship between the answer of the hint and the question

Could someone please help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n(i+j)^2=\left((0+0)^2+\cdots+(n+0)^2\right)+\left((0+1)^2+\cdots+(n+1)^2\right)+\cdots+\left((0+n)^2+\cdots+(n+n)^2\right)$$

This is basically the equivalent of the for loop:

```
x=0;

for i in (0,n):
   for j in (0,n):
      x=x+(i+j)^2
```

According to Wolfram Alpha, this reduces to $\frac{1}{6} n (1 + n)^2 (2 + 7 n)$

---

**Edit:**

The hint can be evaluated as follows. Examine the original sum,
$$(n)(1^2)+(n-1)(2^2)+\cdots+(1)(n^2)$$
Notice that the last term, $(1)(n^2)$, is equivalent to $(n-(n-1))(n^2)$, and each term on the left is 1 less than the previous - so we can rewrite the summation:
$$(n)(1^2)+(n-1)(2^2)+\cdots+(n-(n-1))(n^2)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2(n-i+1)$$
Distribute the terms in the summation
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2(n-i+1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(ni^2-i^3+i^2\right)=n\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3+\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2$$
Combine like terms and rewrite
$$n\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3+\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2=(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3$$
The new expression can be evaluated using your choice of Harmonic numbers, Bernoulli numbers, the Riemann zeta function, etc.; you should get:
$$\left(n+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)\right)-\frac{1}{4}n^2(n+1)^2=\frac{1}{12}n(n+1)^2(n+2)$$
I'm not sure how exactly this relates to the question, except that they both involve summations of squares.
I suppose you could relate them by considering that each partial sum of the original expression is given by a similar summation
$$(0^2+\cdots+n^2)=\sum_{i=0}^n i^2\\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1^2+\cdots+(n+1)^2)=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^2\\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (n^2+\cdots+(n+n)^2)=\sum_{i=n}^{n+n} i^2$$
The total of these is the double summation from my original response:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=i}^{n+i}j^2=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n(i+j)^2$$
I guess you could use generalized harmonic numbers to solve both?...
Sorry, but that's all I've got.

Comment: Thanks.But I still want to know how to find the exact closed form of the hint and make use of the answer of the hint to find the exact closed form of the question.Also I do not know how to get the final answer provided by the Wolfram Alpha,could you please give me more intermediate steps?

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution really inspired me a lot because I previously thought that it would be impossible to solve this question without using the hint.(not just this question, but for all other questions)